# $k$-rational points of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-schemes

> Let $k$ be a field. Show that the $k$-rational points of $\mathbb{P}^n_k=\operatorname{Proj}[x_0,x_1,...,x_n]$ are in bijective correspondence with the points $[a_0,a_1,...,a_n], a_i\in k$ of the projective space.

According to the [Wikipedia page on k-rational points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_point) I have a morphism $f:\mathbb{P}^n_k\to \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ and a $k$-rational point is a section of it $a:\operatorname{Spec}(k)\to \mathbb{P}^n_k$ such that $f\circ a=id_{\operatorname{Spec}(k)}$. Since $\operatorname{Spec}(k)=0$ I get $\mathbb{P}^n_k\overset{f}{\to}0\overset{a}{\to}\mathbb{P}^n_k$ such that $f(a)=0$. How can I show that correspondence and what is that function $f$ specifically?

Comment: What do you mean by $\operatorname{Spec}(k) = 0$? (That is not correct.) Also, the composition you wrote down is in the wrong order. The map $f$ is locally just the structure map of the $k$-algebras $k[x_0/x_i, \dots, k_n/x_i]$.

Comment: @QiZhu if $k$ is a field isn't $Spec(k)=0$? Since I didn't write it you would be correct to assume it's a ring

Comment: Assuming you mean by $0$ the zero object in $\mathbf{Sch}$, no.

Comment: You can find a proof in Qing Liu's book, Lemma 3.43

Answer (score 1):

**Question:** "How can I show that correspondence and what is that function f specifically?"

**Answer:** If $V:=k\{e_0,..,e_n\}$ and $V^*:=k\{x_0,..,x_n\}$ it follows there is a 1-1 correspondence between maps $x: Spec(k) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(V^*):=Proj(Sym_k^*(V^*))$ commuting with the structure map, and rank one quotients $\phi_x: V^* \rightarrow l^* \rightarrow 0$. A rank one quotient $\phi_x$ corresponds 1-1 to a line

$$\phi_x^*: l_x \rightarrow V$$

hence there is a 1-1 correspndence between $k$-rational points $x \in \mathbb{P}(V^*)$ and lines $l_x \subseteq V$.

This is a usage of the tautological sequence. Let $\pi: \mathbb{P}(V^*) \rightarrow Spec(k)$ be the structure map. There is a surjection

$$ T1.\text{   }\pi^*(V^*) \cong V^* \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(V^*)} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(V^*)}(1) \rightarrow 1.$$

By Proposition II.7.12 in Hartshorne, there is a 1-1 correspondence between
maps

$$ x: Spec(k) \rightarrow \mathbb{P}(V^*)$$

with $x \circ \phi = Id$ and the set of rank one quotients

$$\phi_x: id^*(V^*) \cong V^* \rightarrow l^* \rightarrow 0.$$

A rank one quotient $l^*$ dualize to give a canonical line

$$\phi_x^*: l \rightarrow V.$$

Hence we get a 1-1 correspondence

$$\mathbb{P}(V^*)(k) \cong \{ l_x \subseteq V:\text{$l_x$ is a line in $V$} \}.$$

If you dualize the tautological sequence $T1$ and take the fiber at $x$ you get the corresponding line $l_x$:

$$ \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(V^*)}(-1)(x) \cong l_x \subseteq V.$$